# Azure Fabric Service - Actor - for 3rd Party Service monitor (Health Checkup)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have been developing a web API with multiple 3rd party services. I need to monitor that each service is running or not in CRM. And if any have failed, then I need to skip the service until it is turned up.

Here, I need to concentrate,

1. API long pooling service hit (performance).
2. maintain the log for it.
3. control the request based on up/down

What is the best approach to solve it?
Can i create azure service fabric actor for each service health checkup?